# Assist with Python 3, hex, and addition

Tags: python, binary, hex

First time python app, so of course it's not been easy ;)  In plain English this is what I'm trying to do:

> read a binary file in, if any bytes are 0x00 change them to 0xFF, otherwise add 0x01 to each byte and write to a new file.

So there it is..my hope is something like

> ./convert.py file1.bin file2.bin

Here's what I have so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
with open(sys.argv[1], "rb") as f:
        byte = f.read(1)
        while byte:
                # Do stuff with byte.
                if byte = b'\x00'
                        byte = b'\xFF'
                else
                        byte = byte + b'\x01'
                byte = f.read(1)
```

but that's all I have so far...clearly this is very broken.  I figured this would be a good learning opportunity...thanks for any assistance you might be able to give.

Comment: What happens to 0xFF, since adding 0x01 to that takes it out of the range for byte values? Did you mean "if any bytes are 0xFF change them to 0x00...", which would make more sense?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but nope...I really want 0x00 to change to 0xFF.  Right now I get an error with this setup:

  File "./convert.py", line 14
    if byte = b'\xFF'
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Off the top of my head, you need to open a file for writing, probably with `open(sys.argv[2], "wb")`, adding bytes together concatenates them, rather than adding the bytes themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have a bug in the `if byte = b'\x00'` line, you meant `==`. This is one of the most dangerous bugs in software development and that's why python doesn't allow assignment inside a condition.
Second, better check for the length of byte because python reads bytes from file as a list of `bytes`. So, in the end of the file you will get an empty list of `bytes`.

Now for the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys

with open(sys.argv[1], "rb") as fin, open(sys.argv[2], "wb") as fout:
        byte = fin.read(1)
        while len(byte):
                # Do stuff with byte.
                if byte == b'\x00'
                        byte = b'\xFF'
                else
                        byte = bytes((ord(byte) - 1,))
                fout.write(byte)
                byte = fin.read(1)
```

Comment: "if you read a \x00 byte you will not continue to the next iteration because the boolean value of byte in that case is false." That doesn't seem to be right:

`>>> bool(b'\x00')`

`True`

Comment: Wow thanks for this....interestingly I still get an error:

File "./convert.py", line 8
    if byte == b'\x00'
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Wonder if it's my python version?  This is 3.5.1.  Thanks again.

Comment: @DigiAngel You need colons after the if-condition and the else.

Comment: Thank you...I'm getting closer with the below:
`#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys

with open(sys.argv[1], "rb") as fin, open(sys.argv[2], "wb") as fout:
        byte = fin.read(1)
        while len(byte):
                # Do stuff with byte.
                if byte == b'\x00':
                        byte = b'\xFF'
                else:
                        byte = byte + b'\x01'
                fout.write(byte)
                byte = fin.read(1)
`

Comment: Bah....not good with the code formatting.  So my "myfile.bin" has "d0 d1".  When running the above my output file is "d0 01 d1 01" which is not quite right yet.

Comment: Sorry for that. It appears that when you add (+) bytes python concatenates them. You need to convert them to ints before. Will update my answer.

Comment: @mwchase Thanks, removed that part from the answer.

Comment: So close I hope!  The latest error:
`  File "./convert.py", line 12
    fout.write(byte)
                   ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
'

I don't even know what that means....thanks so much again...really appreciate the help!

Comment: Python code wont run if you indent with spaces in one line and tabs in another. Using only spaces to indent python code is best practice.

Comment: Ah...wow I"m learning a lot this AM.  Last error:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./convert.py", line 11, in <module>
    byte = byte(int(byte) + 1)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'\xd0'`

I did not realize adding hex was going to be such a challenge :(  Thank you!

Comment: I have updated the answer to use `ord` which gives the integer value of a character. Try it as I am not in front of a computer.

Comment: Thank you...no error but WOW..crazy results:

`[07:08:16 gamebox:~/Downloads/bad/python$] ./convert.py myfile.bin test.bin`

`[07:19:55 gamebox:~/Downloads/bad/python$] hexdump -C myfile.bin 
00000000  d0 d1 00                                          |...|
00000003`

`[07:20:01 gamebox:~/Downloads/bad/python$] hexdump -C test.bin 
00000000  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001a0  00 00 00 ff                                       |....|
000001a4`

Comment: `bytes` accepts either an iterable... or an int! You must write `byte = bytes((ord(byte) + 1,))` to force it to use the value as the byte code.

Comment: That did it!  Thank you all SO MUCH!

Comment: Ack...this chokes on the FF's:
'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./convert.py", line 12, in <module>
    byte = bytes((ord(byte) + 1,))
ValueError: bytes must be in range(0, 256)
'

verified that it dies on ff.

Comment: Ok this was actually it...I'm an idiot and needed - 1, not +1.  Thanks again all..really appreciate the help.

Comment: Glad to help. You can also consider reading the whole file or chunks of it, manipulate it and writing to the output file. Faster and less demanding on resources.